# Change Caret (Cursor) in Textbox in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, caret

I want to change the Caret in a Textbox in C# that it appears wider like in does in old DOS applications.

What i have: [image]

Example what i want:
[image]

I tried:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

...

```
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  static extern bool CreateCaret(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hBitmap, int nWidth, int nHeight);
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  static extern bool ShowCaret(IntPtr hWnd);
```

...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool CreateCaret(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hBitmap, int nWidth, int nHeight);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateCaret(textBox1.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 20, textBox1.Height);
        ShowCaret(textBox1.Handle);
    }
}
```

But it still looks the same. Any help would be nice. Thanks in advance!

Edit:

This was just an example. My real code looks like:

```
TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
 textbox.MaxLength = fieldLength;
 textbox.Width = fieldLength*24;
 textbox.MaxLength = maxChars;
 this.Controls.Add(textbox);

 CreateCaret(textbox.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 20, textbox.Height);
 ShowCaret(textbox.Handle);
```

The code gets called but doesnt change anything.

Edit2:

I tried the example and it works fine but my problem still exisits:
I cant change the Caret when creating the textbox. Its only possible for a textbox created with the form.

Comment: If anyone is reading this: The answer to my problem was that i called the methods before the form was fully loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't link the event correctly, you should change to :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool CreateCaret(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hBitmap, int nWidth, int nHeight);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Shown += Form1_Shown;
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateCaret(textBox1.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 20, textBox1.Height);
        ShowCaret(textBox1.Handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: When the `Shown` event is double-clicked in the designer's property grid, the event handler is attached in the `.designer.cs`, thus not showing up. In this case however, you are probably correct because the original code seems to work just fine with a correctly attached handler. I'm only adding it because it does not have to that obvious.

Comment: The event handler is usually attached within the forms designer.cs file inside the InitializeComponent method. **Edit** like what Jens said 1 minute earlier :)

Comment: My Code above ist just an example. I call the two methods when i create the textbox programmatically. I only wanted to show what i used. The method gets executed but doesnt affect the appearence

Comment: I tried your example and it works fine. Is it even possible to do this after i create a textbox later?

Comment: @JonasSchafft yeah sure, just put the line `this.Shown += Form1_Shown;` wherever you need

Comment: I guess your answers are right and showed me the direction to my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is going on it seems is that the shown event will only initially work. When you leave the textbox by tabbing away and back to the control the caret will be reset by underlying code.

Take a look the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015699/richtextbox-createcaret-width-measurement) thread.

I took their DrawDaret Method and changed it a bit. Calling DrawCaret on the textbox1.Enter event doesn't work. possibly the textbox implementation will notify the Enter event and then change the caret. This would undo a change done in the Enter event handler regarding to the caret.

**EDIT**

But the control also has a GotFocus event which you can use.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool CreateCaret(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hBitmap, int nWidth, int nHeight);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBox1.GotFocus += new EventHandler(textBox1_GotFocus);
    }

    void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DrawCaret(textBox1);
    }

    public void DrawCaret(Control ctrl)
    {
        var nHeight = 0;
        var nWidth = 10;

        nHeight = Font.Height;

        CreateCaret(ctrl.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, nWidth, nHeight);
        ShowCaret(ctrl.Handle);
    }
}
```